# Re-use a jquery function feeding it a php variable instead of html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

Basically i have a jquery script that reads the value in a drop down list (Country list, the script looks for the hidden ISO value) and displays a flag accordingly using the letters as coordinates on a sprite sheet.

Here is the code:

```
// FLAGS
(function($) {
// size = flag size + spacing
var default_size = {
    w: 20,
    h: 15
};

function calcPos(letter, size) {
    return -(letter.toLowerCase().charCodeAt(0) - 97) * size;
}

$.fn.setFlagPosition = function(iso, size) {
    size || (size = default_size);

    return $(this).css('background-position',
        [calcPos(iso[1], size.w), 'px ', calcPos(iso[0], size.h), 'px'].join(''));
};

// USAGE:
$(function() {
    // on load:
    $('select[name="country"]').on('change', function(){
        $('.country i').setFlagPosition($(this).val())[0].nextSibling.nodeValue =      $(':selected', this).text();
    });
});


})(jQuery);
```

The usage part is probably the relevant part here, but i included everything for completeness.

I would now like to reuse this "sprite searching and displaying code" elsewhere on the site, but instead of relying on the drop down value, i would like it to simply look at the value of a php variable (for example $country) witch will contain an iso code identical to the one provided by the drop down list.

I am unsure how to pass the php variable from php to jquery, and how to make the "usage" part use that instead.

So i have var "$country" and i would like the script to apply its changes to a div called "countryflag".

The sprite is loaded as a background in .country i in the above script by the way, in case someone was wondering how it was fetching it.

Comment: You'd make a PHP script that echos your variable, and make an AJAX request in JavaScript to retrieve it, using JSON in both sides.

Comment: @elclanrs Ok, but what do i add to my Usage part of the js to act on the information in the variable?

Answer (score 0):

You can echo the php variable to a javascript variable as

```
<script>
var country_code = '<?php echo $country; ?>';
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#div_id').setFlagPosition(country_code);
});
</script>
```

If i got it right you can use the country_code as this.

Comment: so i just use that inside <script> tags inside the php script that produces the variable? And what do i add to the usage part of my script to make it act on that information?